# PHP: How to get a value from a JSON file?

Tags: php, json

I'm using PHP and json_decode to use a remote API and I'm having what seems to be a newbie problem for which I didn't even know what to search to find my answer.

So on my script I have a $code = 392 and a json file which simplified version is:

```
{
    "result": {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "New York",
                "code": 7294,
            },
            {
                "name": "Miami",
                "code": 392,
            },
            {
                "name": "Los Angeles",
                "code": 9182,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, simply put, having the code 392 I want to know which name corresponds to that code. How ?
(The actual json result has thousands of "items", if that makes a difference)

Comment: You need to write a `foreach` loop that looks for the code. There's no built-in method to find it in an array like that.

Comment: Just a sidenote on your example JSON, you are not allowed to leave trailing commas like that. PHP's json_decode function, along with several browsers, would be unable to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through `items` in `result` of your JSON object, and check for equality with the desired code, and each item's code. Here's how you would implement it into a function.

```
function getNameFromCode($json, $code) {
    foreach ($json['result']['items'] as $item)
        if ($item['code'] == $code)
           return $item['name'];

    // return false if the code wasn't found.
    return false;
}

// assume this is the JSON string of your example.
$json_string = "...";

// pass true as the second argument to get an associative array.
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);

// should return "Los Angeles".
$name = getNameFromCode($json, 9182);
```

Documenation on **[`foreach()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**.

Answer (score 1):

At first you should decode your json data like:

```
// will decode json data as assoc array
$data = json_decode($json_data, true);
```

Then, you can get value in this array like:

```
$item01 = $data['result']['items'][0];
$name   = $item01['name']; // New York
$code   = $item01['code']; // 7294
```

Or

```
// will decode json data as object
$data = json_decode($json_data);

$item01 = $data->result->items[0];
$name   = $item01->name; // New York
$code   = $item01->code; // 7294
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( json_decode($my_json_string) as $key => $item)
      if ( $item['code'] === $code ) { $name = $item[name]; break; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `JSON` to PHP object and loop through the items with `foreach` loop.

```
function getNameByCode($phpobj, $code){
    if( isset($phpobj->result) ){
        if( isset($phpobj->result->items) 
            && is_array($phpobj->result->items) ){
            foreach($phpobj->result->items as $item){
                if( $item->code == $code ){
                    return $item->name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}//end function
```

You can test with this ... **NOTE: trailing commas are removed** as suggest by *rjdown* in comment

```
$json = '{
"result":     {
    "items": [
                {
                    "name": "New York",
                    "code": 7294
                },
                {
                    "name": "Miami",
                    "code": 392
                },
                {
                    "name": "Los Angeles",
                    "code": 9182
                }
            ]
            }
        }';
$phpobj = json_decode($json); 

$name = getNameByCode($phpobj, "7294");
echo $name;
```